# Cloning SSD to a another SSD?

Tags: ssd

Sorry for asking a lots of questions...
I got a SanDisk X110 128SSD that I want to clone all the stuff to a Corsair Force GT 240.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my Dad would say, "[t]here's more than one way to skin a cat". If you're familiar with [gparted](http://gparted.org/) it should pe pretty straight forward.

- Boot up a live version of the OS (presumably the USB or DVD you used to install). This is so that neither of you drives are mounted while you move things around.
- You could re-size the partition which shouldn't be *necessary* since you're moving up in drive capacity.
- Copy your partition over. This should use the same UUID for the copied partition. If you're wanting boot from both the old copy of the drive *and* the new one going forward then we can edit the [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) file. But we can burn that bridge when we come to it
- Install grub on the new drive.

After that you should be set. However it would be prudent to save the original copy for a bit; there's always risk when doing this for the first time.